Is it possible to recover non-reserve tokens accidentally sent to a Uniswap V2 Pair contract?
I'm trying to understand the operation and potential pitfalls of interacting with UniswapV2Pair contracts. I'm aware that if excess token0 or token1 are sent to a Pair contract, it may be possible to recover them using the contract's skim function.
However, what confuses me is the scenario where tokens -- that do not belong to the pair's reserves -- are sent directly to the Pair contract. The contract's code does not seem to directly handle or provide a withdrawal mechanism for such tokens.
My first question is, could these non-reserve tokens possibly be retrieved with an external contract? For instance, a contract that performs a swap while also transferring the stuck tokens from the UniswapV2 Pair?
My second question is, why don't we see more situations where funds appear to be indefinitely stuck in a UniswapV2Pair? I often observe tokens accidentally sent directly to token contracts, which is why so many token contracts include methods to rescue stuck ETH or tokens. Yet, this issue seems less common with Uniswap V2 Pair contracts, and I'm curious as to why and how this is the case.
I realize retrieving stuck tokens might be unfeasible or complicated, but any insights or examples of tokens being retrieved from a pair, when the tokens aren't part of the reserves, would be much appreciated.


My first question is, could these non-reserve tokens possibly be retrieved with an external contract?

No. Uniswap V2 pair contracts do not have ownership or recovery mechanism for random tokens.
